# API Key for Azure Machine Learning Endpoint

Tags: azure, machine-learning, endpoint, azure-machine-learning-service, automl

I am using Azure ML, I made my models and now I want to connect them to Data Factory to run some process.

I implement an endpoint, but I can't find the API key for the endpoints. Right now, I have the REST endpoint, but not in key-based authentication enabled, it's false. Do you know how to generate the API key?

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only way to retrieve the token is by using the Azure Machine Learning SDK or the Azure CLI machine learning extension.

[image]

Key-based auth is supported for Azure Container Instance and Azure Kubernetes Service deployed web-services, and token-based auth is only available for Azure Kubernetes Service deployments.

You can find more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azureml/online-endpoints/regenerate-keys)